# Updating the head node automatically after inserting new node at the beginning of the linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have this Code for adding new node to my linked list, I want to add the new node at the beginning of the list ,I wrote this code on the insert function ,

```
Node insert(Node start, int x){
    Node newNode = new Node(x);
    if(start == null) {
        return start = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode.next = start;
        start = newNode;
    }
    return start;
}
```

And this is my main class ,Is there any other way to do it more efficiently ?

```
LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
Node startPoint=new Node(20);  
Node newNode=list.insert(startPoint, 16);
Node newNode1=list.insert(newNode, 22);
Node newNode2=list.insert(newNode1, 2);
Node newNode3=list.insert(newNode2, 5);
Node newNode4=list.insert(newNode3, 44);
Node newNode5=list.insert(newNode4, 77);
```

Comment: When you say efficiently, you mean in terms of execution time? I doubt it. There's not much going on really. Personally, I would skip the `return` part in the first branch. It makes it clear that `start` is always returned, regardless of which branch is taken.

Comment: You mean the if section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency is fine, but you can make it more elegant.

First of all, your main program should not have to know about *nodes*. It should just have to create the linked list instance, and add integers to it. Your main code now maintains some *state* (like `startPoint`) that actually the linked list instance should manage for you. It should maintain a reference to the first node in its list (which starts as `null`): often this is called `head`.

Since you write that you *"...want to add the new node at the beginning of the list"*, you would not need to pass a node as argument to `insert`. The linked instance can use its `head` member to do the insertion just before it, and then update its `head` to refer to that new node. The `insert` method should also not need to return the newly created node. The caller should not have to worry about such implementation details.

Finally, you could add a Node constructor overload that accepts a reference for its `next` member. This would help to make your `insert` method very concise.

So, make your Node constructors like this (I assume the value member is called `value`, if you used a different name, like `data`, adapt as needed):

```
class Node {
    private final int value;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    /* ... other methods */
}
```

Then in your linked list class, make sure you have a `head` member, and define your `insert` method such that it only takes a value argument:

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    void insert(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    /* other methods ... */
}
```

And then your main program could do:

```
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.insert(20);
    list.insert(16);
    list.insert(22);
    list.insert(2);
    /* ...etc... */
```

Of course, you would need to add methods that allow you to retrieve values from the list, and perform other interesting actions on it.

Answer (score 3):

> And this is my main class ,Is there any other way to do it more efficiently ?

There is not.
This is the [classical](https://www.log2base2.com/data-structures/linked-list/inserting-a-node-at-the-beginning-of-a-linked-list.html) solution to this problem.

The reason why you can't do any better that this, is because this implementation of this operation takes `O(1)` time. Which is really cool and sexy, because the time to perform it does not depend on the size of the input, which is a really cool property to have on large data sets.

You can continue exercising your DS skills by implementing more complex operations with linked lists, such as insertion into an arbitrary position in the list or reversal of a linked list.